# Represent a word with an alphabet

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, count

This is an interview question:

```
Imagine an alphabet of words. Example:
a ==> 1
b ==> 2
c ==> 3
.
z ==> 26
ab ==> 27
ac ==> 28
.
az ==> 51
bc ==> 52
and so on.
```

Such that the sequence of characters need to be in ascending order only (ab is valid but ba is not). Given any word print its index if valid and 0 if not.

```
Input Output
ab 27
ba 0
aez 441
```

Note: Brute-force is not allowed. Here is the link to the question: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=21117662

I can understand that solution as:

- The total words is 2^26 -1.
- For a given word, the words with small size occurs first.
- Let n be the length of the word,

  - Total number of words with size less than n is C(26, 1) + C(26, 2) + ...+ C(26, n -1)
- Then calculate how many words with the same size prior to the given word
- The sum of two numbers plusing one is the result

Reference: sites.google.com/site/spaceofjameschen/annnocements/printtheindexofawordwithlettersinascendingorder--microsoft

In the sample solution, I understood how the author calculated number of words with size less than word.size(). But, in the code, I am not too sure about how to find number of words of the same size as word.size() that occur before 'word'.

Precisely, this bit:

```
char desirableStart;  
i = 0;
while( i < str.size()){     
    desirableStart = (i == 0) ? 'a' : str[i - 1] + 1;   

    for(int j = desirableStart; j < str[i]; ++j){
        index += NChooseK('z' - j, str.size() - i - 1);     // Choose str.size() - i - 1 in the available charset
    }

    i ++;
}
```

Can someone help me understand this bit? Thanks.

Comment: You should study the problem on paper before you write any code.  Attempt examples, design and test algorithms, and prove correctness. Coding is a distraction. Computers can help you calculate, but they can't help you *think*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all (you probably got this part, but for completeness sake), the `NChooseK` function calculates the binomial coefficient, i.e. the number of ways to choose *k* elements from a set of *n* elements. This function is referred to as `C(n, k)` in your comments, so I will use the same notation.

Since the letters are sorted and not repeating, this is exactly the number of ways one can create the *n*-letter words described in the problem, so this is why the first part of the function is getting you at the right position:

```
int index = 0;
int i = 1;

while(i < str.size()) {
    // choose *i* letters out of 26
    index += NChooseK(26, i);
    i++;
}
```

For example, if your input was `aez`, this would get the index of the word `yz`, which is the last possible 2-letter combination: `C(26, 1) + C(26, 2) = 351`.

At this point, you have the initial index of your *n*-letter word, and need to see how many combinations of *n*-letter words you need to skip to get to the end of the word. To do this, you have to check each individual letter and count all possible combinations of letters starting with one letter after the previous one (the `desirableStart` variable in your code), and ending with the letter being examined.

For example, for `aez` you would proceed as following:

1. Get the last 2-letter word index (`yz`).
2. Increase index by one (this is actually done at the end of your code, but it makes more sense to do it here to keep the correct positions): now we are at index of `abc`.
3. First letter is `a`, no need to increase. You are still at `abc`.
4. Second letter is `e`, count combinations for 2nd letter from `b` to `e`. This will get you to `aef` (note that `f` is the first valid 3rd character in this example, and `desirableStart` takes care of that).
5. Third letter is `z`, count combinations for 3rd letter, from `f` to `z`. This will get you to `aez`.

That's what the last part of your code does:

```
// get to str.size() initial index (moved this line up)
index ++;

i = 0;
while( i < str.size()) { 

    // if previous letter was `e`, we need to start with `f`
    desirableStart = (i == 0) ? 'a' : str[i - 1] + 1;   

    // add all combinations until you get to the current letter
    for (int j = desirableStart; j < str[i]; ++j) {

        char validLettersRemaining = 'z' - j;
        int numberOfLettersToChoose = str.size() - i - 1;
        index += NChooseK(validLettersRemaining, numberOfLettersToChoose);
    }

    i++;
}

return index;
```

Comment: Read this explanation again after 3 years, and still understood the explanation in a single read. Is there a way I could give this answer a "Double Like"?! :)

Comment: @Darth.Vader: thanks a lot, that's nice to hear. Honestly, it's morning in my country, I am drinking my first coffee, and I have no clue what this code is all about. :)

Comment: that's what happens when i write some code while I am half asleep and wake up next morning only to wonder: who the eff wrote this last night.. it wasn't me.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference between the computation of the number of words of the same size and the  counterpart for shorter words.

you may be led astray by the indexing of arrays in c which starts at 0. thus though `i < str.size()` might suggest otherwise, the last iteration of this loop actually counts words of the same size as that of the word whose index is computed.